# how to replace a string with another string only on the last word of each line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I want to replace the 'UN' in the last word of each line with 'LK'.

Input file :

```
Y'UN 310R 07MAR DAUNEN UN2    
Y'UN 720R 07MAR DENSUN HK2    
Y'UN 721R 14MAR UNDDEN HK2    
Y'UN1692R 14MAR DEUNAY UN2
```

Output needed :

```
Y'UN 310R 07MAR DAUNEN LK2    
Y'UN 720R 07MAR DENSUN HK2    
Y'UN 721R 14MAR UNDDEN HK2    
Y'UN1692R 14MAR DEUNAY LK2
```

Comment: Are those blank lines present in your input, or were you just trying to separate each line of your data? Have you tried anything? This is very simple stuff.

Comment: Will the last UN always have number(s) too?

Comment: There is no empty lines between the data. Yes the UN always have a number with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is using the 'end of line' anchor - `$`

```
sed -e 's/UN\([A-Z0-9]*\)$/LK\1/'
```

Comment: @DheebanChakkaravarthy it is replaced with matched content from the first pair of `()`, basic regular expression stuff

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/UN/, "LK", $NF)}1' File
```

In the last field in each line (`$NF`), replace pattern UN (`/UN/`) with string LK (`"LK"`). Print the unaffected lines as well (`1`).

Output:

```
Y'UN 310R 07MAR DAUNEN LK2

Y'UN 720R 07MAR DENSUN HK2

Y'UN 721R 14MAR UNDDEN HK2

Y'UN1692R 14MAR DEUNAY LK2
```

Comment: Your choice of syntax means that the output of sub is being interpreted as a string then concatenated with a string `"1"`, so it does what you want but in quite a weird way. I'd recommend `awk '{ sub(/UN/, "LK", $NF) }1'` or even just write the `print` statement explicitly.

Comment: @TomFenech is 100% correct. We actually had a discussion about this on comp.lang.awk about 15 years ago and all agreed that the syntax shown here should never be used even though it's slightly briefer than doing it the clearer way with the action (`sub()`) in an action block and condition (`1`) in the condition section.

Comment: Oops...thanks guys for pointing that out... actually this was not what i actually wanted and missed the brackets because of the correct output..